# Implicit macro. Default implicit value. How?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-macros

I don't even know how to ask the question.

I have a macro that creates an instance of `IsEnum[T]` for a type `T`.

I'm doing testing for it, and want to make sure that the implicit is not found for types that are not sealed, or that, in general, don't meet the requirements of an enum.

So I created this method for testing

```scala
    def enumOf[T](implicit isEnum:IsEnum[T] = null) = isEnum
```

And then I ensure that `enumOf[NotAnEnum] == null`

But instead, it fails at compile time.

One thing is the macro erroring. Another thing is the macro just not applying for a given case. How to make that distinction when creating macros?

Edit: I've used `c.abort` and `c.error`, both giving me the same results.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ (offtopic) Why did you remove tag `macros`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't make your macro materializing type class `IsEnum` whitebox. Normally implicit macros should be whitebox.

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

trait IsEnum[T]
object IsEnum {
  implicit def mkIsEnum[T]: IsEnum[T] = macro mkIsEnumImpl[T]
  def mkIsEnumImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val typ = weakTypeOf[T]
    val classSymbol = typ.typeSymbol.asClass
    if (!classSymbol.isTrait || !classSymbol.isSealed) c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"$typ must be sealed trait")
    val symbols = classSymbol.knownDirectSubclasses
    symbols.collectFirst {
      case symbol if !symbol.isModuleClass || !symbol.asClass.isCaseClass =>
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"${symbol.asClass.toType} must be case object")
    }
    q"new IsEnum[$typ] {}"
  }
}

def enumOf[T](implicit isEnum: IsEnum[T] = null) = isEnum
```

Usage:

```
sealed trait A
object A {
  case object B extends A
  case object C extends A
  case class D() extends A
}
enumOf[A] //null

sealed trait A
object A {
  case object B extends A
  case object C extends A
  class D extends A
}
enumOf[A] //null

sealed trait A
object A {
  case object B extends A
  object C extends A
}
enumOf[A] //null

trait A
object A {
  case object B extends A
  case object C extends A
}
enumOf[A] //null

sealed trait A
object A {
  case object B extends A
  case object C extends A
}
enumOf[A] //App$$anon$1@47f37ef1
```

Runtime of macros is compile time of main code. If a blackbox macro (even implicit blackbox macro) throws an exception then it will be a compile error during compilation of main code. If a whitebox implicit macro throws an exception then during compilation of main code the implicit will be silently removed from candidates.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/blackbox-whitebox.html

Comment: You've helped me in my last two questions a lot! This is very very helpful! And weird!