# what should a scala implicit macro have to return to tell the compiler "forget my result, continue your search"

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-macros

I have an implicit macro with a greedy signature

```
implicit def materializeHelper[C <: Any]: Helper[C] = macro materializeHelperImpl[C]

def materializeHelperImpl[C <: Any: ctx.WeakTypeTag](ctx: blackbox.Context): ctx.Expr[Helper[C]] = ???
```

According to it's signature it would materialize a `Helper[C]` for any C. But the body is much more picky. It only accepts `C`s which are sealed traits.
What should the macro return to tell the compiler "forget my result, continue your implicit search as if I didn't exist"?

Currently I am returning an empty block (`q""`), which is not ideal because the compiler materializes a `null` when said implicit is used as an intermediate rule. For example, in the following line, the `helper` parameter is set to null when the macro returns empty (`q""`).

```
implicit def parser[C <: Any](implicit helper: Helper[C]): Parser[C] = new Parser[C](helper)
```

And my intention is that, in the case that `C` is not a sealed trait, the compiler discards both beforementioned implicit and continue the search for another more specific implicit value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122310/implicit-macro-default-implicit-value-how Does this answer your question?

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yes, I think so. Then, if I changed the macro type to white box, should I abort it or returning an empty block (`q""`) is ok too?

Comment: @DmytroMitin Please, put your comment as an answer so I can check it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Apparently, when the macro type is white, returning an empty block also tells the compiler to discard the value.

Comment: Idiomatical is to call `c.abort` with custom error message. Throwing an exception, calling `c.error`, returning `EmptyTree` (it just doesn't typecheck in such case but it's better to have clear compile error message) are also possible although they seem a little less idiomatical.

Comment: If the question linked answers yours then I guess I'll just close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps it is a duplicate answer. But I think this isn't a duplicate question because the question you mention is very different. I would never find it based on its title.
A default value is not the same than instructing to continue the search.

Comment: Ok, I reopened and submitted an answer. Let's hope now this is searchable better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't make your macro materializing type class `Helper` whitebox.

> Normally implicit macros should be whitebox.

> If a blackbox macro (even implicit blackbox macro) throws an exception
> then it will be a compile error during compilation of main code. If a
> whitebox implicit macro throws an exception then during compilation of
> main code the implicit will be silently removed from candidates.

[Implicit macro. Default implicit value. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122310/implicit-macro-default-implicit-value-how)

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/blackbox-whitebox.html

It's more idiomatical to call `c.abort` with custom error message. Throwing an exception, calling `c.error`, returning `EmptyTree` (it just doesn't typecheck in such case) are also possible although they seem a little less idiomatical (it's better to have clear compile error message).