# Implicit materialization in the same module

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros

I have a parameterized class like

```
class Test[T]{
    //...
}

object Test{
    implicit def materializeTest[T]: Test[T] = macro impl[T]

    def impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context) = //...
}
```

If using the materialized implicit from the same module it throws an error:

```
macro implementation not found
```

But the problem is extracting a single class into a separate module looks absolutely ugly and cumbersome. Maybe there is some "well-known workaround" to avoid that? Maybe shapeless can be helpful here?

UPD:

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.13.2"
```

Here is my minimal example:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Main {
  sealed trait Adt
  case object Adt1 extends Adt
  case object Adt2 extends Adt

  trait Test[Adtt <: Adt] {
    def restrict(restrictions: List[Int]): List[Int]
  }

  object Test {
    def apply[Adtt <: Adt](implicit ev: Test[Adtt]): Test[Adtt] = ev

    implicit def implicitMaterializer[
        Adtt <: Adt
    ]: Test[Adtt] = macro impl[Adtt]

    def impl[Adtt <: Adt: c.WeakTypeTag](
        c: blackbox.Context
    ): c.Expr[Test[Adtt]] = {

      import c.universe._
      c.Expr[Test[Adtt]](q"""???""")
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Test[Adt1.type].restrict(List(1, 2, 3))
  }
}
```

which results in the following error:

```
[error] Main.scala:32:9: macro implementation not found: implicitMaterializer
[error] (the most common reason for that is that you cannot use macro implementations in the same compilation run that defines them)
```

Comment: Why did you make implicit macro blackbox? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64538997/what-should-a-scala-implicit-macro-have-to-return-to-tell-the-compiler-forget-m/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122310/implicit-macro-default-implicit-value-how

Comment: @DmytroMitin I made it blackbox to provide better error messages without silently ignoring it.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I added the MCVE I got this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract to a separate module not `Test` but `TestMacro`

*core*

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros

class Test[T]

object Test {
  implicit def materializeTest[T]: Test[T] = macro TestMacro.impl[T]
}

implicitly[Test[Int]] // compiles
```

*macros*

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object TestMacro {
  def impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context) = {
    import c.universe._
    q"new Test[${weakTypeOf[T]}]"
  }
}
```

Ugly or not but macro implementations must be compiled before they are applied (but [Is there any trick to use macros in the same file they are defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919726/is-there-any-trick-to-use-macros-in-the-same-file-they-are-defined)).

This is improved in Scala 3

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html#defining-a-macro-and-using-it-in-a-single-project

Shapeless just hides some predefined set of standard macros, it can't help with your own macros.